# Return large/streaming responses via webapp2 on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm building a web app for GAE where logged-in users may download potentially large files. How do I construct such responses (or comet responses)? I believe the webapp2 `Response` object fully buffers and has no `flush()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store the file in a blob and let the user download the blob.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview

Comment: Very interesting - is this the only approach?

Comment: You can implement a similar solution using Google Cloud Storage too.

Comment: It is the best option for large files, because you can use GAE tasks or chained tasks or a backend to create the blob to overcome request deadlines.
And there is another new option: Google Drive. Drive is more suited for personal data. I have not seen or found an application or utility yet, where drive data is exchanged with the blobstore or google cloud storage.

Comment: What if I wanted to control the response timing as in comet? I.e. I'm not sending back a big file but rather sending back a stream of "notifications" in on http response (commonly used in ajax apps)?